# CefSharp: is it possible to manage DevTools emulation programmatically?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

I'm wondering is it possible to manage DevTools emulation programmatically?
I need to start browser in IPhone6 mode automatically. Without switching the mode manually...

Thank you!

Comment: You might be able to do it with remote debugging by sending commands to the debugger. Take a look at this thread and see if it helps.
http://www.magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=11952